# Limit records in query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is My Query

```
SELECT 
  [MO].[Id] AS [ObjectId],
  [CA].[Id] As [CategoryId],
  [GR].[Id] AS [GroupId]
FROM [MYOBJECT] AZ [MO]
INNER JOIN [Category] AS [CA] ON [CA].[Id] = [MO].[CategoryId]
Inner Join [Group] AS [GR] ON [GR].[CategoryId] = [CA].[ID]
```

The result is:

```
ObjectId    CategoryId   GroupId
-----------------------------------
1             1           1
1             2           2
2             1           1
2             2           2
```

But I need the Distinct on `ObjectId` I mean the `categoryid` and `groupid` is not important for me I need something like the following:

```
 ObjectId    CategoryId   GroupId
-----------------------------------
1             1           1
2             1           1
```

Or

```
ObjectId    CategoryId   GroupId
-----------------------------------
1             2           2
2             1           1
```

both of the above result is fine for me and both of them as you see is real record (as you see in first query)

So, how can I get this result? what is the fastest way to do this? any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and use some aggregate function on the other columns:

```
SELECT 
  [MO].[Id] AS [ObjectId],
  MIN([CA].[Id]) As [CategoryId],
  MIN([GR].[Id]) AS [GroupId]
FROM [MYOBJECT] AZ [MO]
INNER JOIN [Category] AS [CA] ON [CA].[Id] = [MO].[CategoryId]
Inner Join [Group] AS [GR] ON [GR].[CategoryId] = [CA].[ID]
GROUP BY [MO].[Id]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [MO].[Id] ORDER BY [CA].[Id]) As rno
  [MO].[Id] AS [ObjectId],
  [CA].[Id] As [CategoryId],
  [GR].[Id] AS [GroupId]
FROM [MYOBJECT] AZ [MO]
INNER JOIN [Category] AS [CA] ON [CA].[Id] = [MO].[CategoryId]
INNER JOIN [Group] AS [GR] ON [GR].[CategoryId] = [CA].[ID]
)

SELECT * 
FROM cte WHERE rno=1
```

Or you can use like this since CategoryId and  GroupId are not important

```
SELECT 
  [MO].[Id] AS [ObjectId],
  MAX([CA].[Id]) As [CategoryId],
  MAX([GR].[Id]) AS [GroupId]
FROM [MYOBJECT] AZ [MO]
INNER JOIN [Category] AS [CA] ON [CA].[Id] = [MO].[CategoryId]
INNER JOIN [Group] AS [GR] ON [GR].[CategoryId] = [CA].[ID]
GROUP BY  [MO].[Id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what came to my mind.  The Row_Number function will issue an auto-incremented number for each row in your partition by clause, in this case the ObjectId or MO.Id.  Then in the outer select we return the other columns and filter by the new RowNum column.

```
 SELECT A.ObjectId, 
           A.CategoryId ,
           A.GroupId
  FROM  (
            SELECT 
              [MO].[Id] AS [ObjectId],
              [CA].[Id] As [CategoryId],
              [GR].[Id] AS [GroupId],
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [MO].[Id]) AS RowNum
            FROM [MYOBJECT] AZ [MO]
            INNER JOIN [Category] AS [CA] ON [CA].[Id] = [MO].[CategoryId]
            INNER JOIN [Group] AS [GR] ON [GR].[CategoryId] = [CA].[ID]
        ) A
  WHERE A.RowNum = 1
```